# How to remove a specific field value from Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

My pivot table is sourcing data from a dynamic table where the number of rows can increase or decrease based on certain conditions.

As such, the range for my data source is something like `$A:$M` so that it captures every possible row regardless of how the table resizes. But because of that, each field in the pivot table now has a (blank) value because of those empty rows.

Is there a way to remove these (blank) field values in the pivot table?

I have tried manually filtering out the blanks. But because the pivot table automatically updates based on the user selecting certain slicers, it messes up the filtering - so that approach is a no go.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of using the range like that, format your data as a Table, then set the pivot table source as the name of the Table. 

As new rows are added to the Table, the pivot table will always include them.

Comment: Otherwise, you may press Ctrl+F to replace (blank) field values with real blank.